# How can i call from another method a linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2010

In this method I create the linq. Linq works fine, I can see the data correctly but the problem is that I need to be able to call that from another method.

```
  protected IQueryable method ()
    {

        var v = (from a in BAS1
                 join b in BAS2 on a.TIP equals b.TIP 
                 join c in BAS3 on a.COM equals c.COM 
                 join d in BAS4 on c.PROV equals d.PROV 
                 join e in BAS5 on d.ID_REG equals e.ID_REG

                 select new
                 {
                     a.ID,
                     b.SIG,
                     e.ID_REG,

                 });

        return v.ToString();
    }
```

And from this method I want to take the linq and filter it, but it shows me error in the  **v = v.Where(x => ....**

```
 public ActionResult method2() {

        var v = method ();
        var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        var filter_sig = Request.QueryString["filter_sig"];
        var filter_reg = Request.QueryString["filter_reg"];
if (filter_sig!= "")
        {
            decimal dfiltesig = decimal.Parse(filter_sig);
            v = v.Where(x => x.SIG==dfiltesig );
        }

if (id!= "")
        {
            v = v.Where(x => x.ID.ToLower().Contains(id.ToLower()));
        }

if (filter_reg!= "")
        {
            v = v.Where(x => x.ID_REG.ToLower().Contains(filter_reg.ToLower()));
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that `ToString()` call from your return statement `return v.ToString();` and rather return only the query saying

```
return v;
```

Comment: Try it but still showing error. It says "Can not convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyThing {
   public string ID {get;set;}
   public string ID_REG {get;set;}
   public decimal SIG {get;set;}
}

protected IQueryable<MyThing> method()
{
    return (from a in BAS1
             join b in BAS2 on a.TIP equals b.TIP 
             join c in BAS3 on a.COM equals c.COM 
             join d in BAS4 on c.PROV equals d.PROV 
             join e in BAS5 on d.ID_REG equals e.ID_REG

             select new MyThing
             {
                 a.ID,
                 b.SIG,
                 e.ID_REG,
             });
}
```

Comment: I can not do that, because the attributes I have in the Models folder and this I am doing from the Controller folder

Comment: You can't do what?

Comment: Is that I'm doing it with MVC